# Easier way to do element- wise matrix multiplication for pairs in a given matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, pairwise, elementwise-operations

I have a matrix of dimension **n*k** and I am trying to calculate another matrix which has all the pairs which will have *n(n-1)/2* rows and *k* columns

New columns are element-wise multiplication of two different individual rows.

Below is the code,how i am calculating it currently:

```
mat = matrix(rnorm(10000,mean = 0,sd = 1), nrow = 100, ncol = 100) # n = 100, k = 100

mat2 = matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(mat)*(nrow(mat)-1)/2, ncol = ncol(mat))

counter = 0

for(i in seq(nrow(mat))){
    # print(paste('i', i))
    for(j in seq(nrow(mat))){
        # print(paste('j', j))
        if((i!= j)&(i<j)){
            
            x = mat[i,]*mat[j,]
            # print(x)
            
            mat2 = rbind(mat2, x)
            counter = counter + 1
            print(paste('Counter - ', counter,' : Pair(', i,',', j, ')', sep = ''))
        }
           
    }
}
```

Its very brute force approach though with O(n^2). Is there a way to do the same computation with less time ?

Comment: you could try `idx = combn(nrow(mat), 2); mat[idx[1,], ]  * mat[idx[2,], ] ` (not really tested!!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked pretty fast compared to what I was doing !